# "Did you mean this ?" Google site search and views exposed filter integration

Tags: views, search

Is there a way to use Google site search to search through Views Exposed Filters. Basically for autosuggestion and "did you mean this".

Comment: **Did you mean this ?** I believe that the only way to do that it by using Solr server. You probably would need to use search api solr or the apache solr